# Creating tables in OpenAPI 3 through Commonmark

Tags: openapi, commonmark

In Swagger/OpenAPI 2, I used Markdown tables, something like this:

```
| A | B | C |
|---|---|---|
| T | F | F |
| T | F | T |
```

But after upgrading to OpenAPI 3, where Commonmark is used instead of Github-flavoured Markdown, it seems that the tables aren't supported anymore. Are there any alternatives to this, or alternatives to displaying data in a tabular form?

Comment: The CommonMark spec does not support tables at this time, and it's unknown whether it will in the future.

Comment: @ColinO'Dell Indeed, so I was wondering what sorts of other alternatives there are to displaying data in table-like forms. I tried plain-text tables, but those didn't format quite that well unfortunately.

Comment: Until tables are standardized in CommonMark I would suggest just following the GitHub conventions.  That should provide you with the most comprehensive tooling support.

Answer (score 1):

CommonMark supports [html blocks](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#html-blocks), so you can embed html tables in your OpenAPI 3.0.x descriptions etc, at the expense of some readability.